# Twitter API V2 RecentSearch returns retweets with truncated text

Tags: api, twitter, tweets, truncated

I have been looking everywhere for a solution to this problem. Most questions and answers about this topic are from a few years ago when people were still using api v1.1.

If I perform a recent search, the resulting retweet(s) are almost always truncated.

Here are the text fields for some formatted results of a search for "Canada":

> RT @iam_bigosas: You traveled to Canada with your husband in search of
> greener pasture and unfortunately he got deported. As a wife will yo…
>
> RT @The12fthOfNever: Canada has given full approval to the single-dose
> Johnson Johnson vaccine, the company has said. The vaccine has bee…
>
> Profound statement “Racism NOT race is a social determinant of health
> which contributes to unacceptable health & social inequities.”
> #CNA2021 helping all Canada  nurses to look inward today at this summit on anti racism. Read the statement again, hold it close...
>
> RT @Canadian_Crown: This 1957 portrait by Canadian artist L. Newton of
> the 31-year-old Queen Elizabeth II is found in Canada’s Parliament B…
>
> RT @mastervokeh: Watu wame enda majuu ebu ni ambieni ni route gani
> hainanga jam uki elekea Canada?

You can see that retweets (denoted by a RT) are truncated if they are too long. The one non-retweet is displayed in full. I'm doing a data mining project for school and I need the full text. Twitters API v2 only mentions how to get the ids of the mentioned tweets, not the full text.

Using the "references_tweets" flag that I found in the documentation only adds type and id of retweets:

Here is an example:
Text from RecentSearch: Family-owned Ontario ice cream-maker @Chapmans_Canada was paying for COVID tests for unvaccinated staff. So to be fair,...

When I find this tweet on twitter.com, this is the text:

> Family-owned Ontario ice cream-maker  @Chapmans_Canada  was paying for
> COVID tests for unvaccinated staff. So to be fair, they decided to
> reward employees who did get vaxxed with $1/hour raise.  The result:
> anti-vaxxers scream for boycott & harass owners.

Does anyone know I this is possible? I know I could get the referenced tweet id and download that separately, but I'm hoping that is unnecessary, as I need to download about 100000 tweets and I would like to keep my api requests to a minimum.